# Property 'throw' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'

Tags: nativescript-angular

Iam learning nativescript+angular for developing android and ios apps.Iam working and learning basic services of nativescript+angular.In the post method of the my project i have the error 'property 'throw' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'.
My Code is:

```
import { User } from "./user";
import { Config } from "../config";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "tns-core-modules/ui/page/page";

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    register(user: User) {
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

        return this.http.post(
            Config.apiUrl + "Users",
            JSON.stringify({
                Username: user.email,
                Email: user.email,
                Password: user.password
            }),
            { headers: headers }
        )
            .catch(this.handleErrors);

    }

    handleErrors(error:Response)
    {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error.json()));
        return Observable.throw(error);        
    }



}
```

Comment: what RxJs version?

Comment: sorry iam new to nativscript and angular. i dont know RxJs

Comment: [RxJs](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#observable) is the library that provides observables that are used in Angular. RxJs version is important because `Obserble.throw` is now deprecated in recent versions of RxJs, and people should use `throwError` instead (see @slejnej answer below).

Comment: I also observe that you wrote `import { Observable } from "tns-core-modules/ui/page/page";` instead of the `import { Observable } from 'rxjs';` [used in web dev](https://angular.io/guide/rx-library). Is that an error or what is on purpose?

Answer (score 22):

Observable.throw is now deprecated. You have to use this instead:

```
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';
```

then replace your `Observable.throw` with `throwError("Your error")`.
Your subscriber to observable will picked it up in the same way it did in the past.

[Check here @ #287](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Observable.ts)

Answer (score 10):

Observable.throw and throwError("Your error") are now deprecated. Now, you should use a factory directly as `throwError(() => new Error('Your error'))`

[Check here](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/throwError)